# Intel XDK doesn't start

Tags: intel-xdk

Daar Sirs, I am facing difficulties in understanding why Intel XDK doesn't start. Here I have attached the log file. So far I tried to change the localhost from 0.0.0.0 to 172.0.0.1 with no results. If you can help me that would be great. Thanks. Marco

```
xdk:client (1413019122720): Intel XDK: 1332
xdk:client (1413019122721): Platform: win32-ia32 (6.1.7601)
xdk:client (1413019122782): Starting client process initialization
xdk:server (1413019123552): Starting server process initialization
xdk:server (1413019123742): Http server started on the standard port 58889
xdk:server (1413019123748): Component "core:assert" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123748): Component "core:assert" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123748): Component "core:component-error" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123749): Component "core:component-error" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123749): Component "core:command-line-options" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123749): Component "core:command-line-options" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123749): Component "core:service-error" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123749): Component "core:service-error" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123749): Component "core:buffer" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123750): Component "core:buffer" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123750): Component "core:signaler" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123754): Component "core:signaler" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123754): Component "core:signaler-group" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123756): Component "core:signaler-group" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123756): Component "core:logger" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123758): Component "core:logger" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123758): Component "core:http-request" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123762): Component "core:http-request" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123763): Component "core:database" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123764): Component "core:database" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123764): Component "core:version" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123764): Component "core:version" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123764): Component "core:userfs-name-converter" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123765): Component "core:userfs-name-converter" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123765): Component "core:crash-handler" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123770): Component "core:crash-handler" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123770): Component "core:i18n-support" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123770): Component "core:i18n-support" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123772): Component "server:userfs" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123783): Component "server:userfs" calling init()
xdk:server (1413019123834): Component "server:userfs" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123835): Component "server:user-profile" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123839): Component "server:user-profile" calling init()
xdk:server (1413019123839): Component "server:user-profile" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123839): Component "server:projectInfo" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123841): Component "server:projectInfo" calling init()
xdk:server (1413019123841): Component "server:projectInfo" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123841): Component "server:ui-builder" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123918): Component "server:ui-builder" calling init()
xdk:server (1413019123920): Component "server:ui-builder" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123920): Component "server:emulator-notification" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123925): Component "server:emulator-notification" calling init()
xdk:server (1413019123926): Component "server:emulator-notification" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123926): Component "server:emulator-webserver" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123927): Component "server:emulator-webserver" calling init()
xdk:server (1413019123928): Component "server:emulator-webserver" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123928): Component "server:new-project-creator" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123933): Component "server:new-project-creator" calling init()
xdk:server (1413019123934): Component "server:new-project-creator" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123934): Component "server:zip-util" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123938): Component "server:zip-util" calling init()
xdk:server (1413019123938): Component "server:zip-util" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123938): Component "server:uuid-server" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123943): Component "server:uuid-server" calling init()
xdk:server (1413019123943): Component "server:uuid-server" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123943): Component "server:app-starter" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123953): Component "server:app-starter" calling init()
xdk:server (1413019123956): Component "server:app-starter" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123956): Component "server:force-download" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123960): Component "server:force-download" calling init()
xdk:server (1413019123961): Component "server:force-download" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123961): Component "server:updater" starting import
xdk:server (1413019123969): Component "server:updater" calling init()
xdk:server (1413019123970): Component "server:updater" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019123970): Component "server:editor-node" starting import
xdk:server (1413019124031): Component "server:editor-node" calling init()
xdk:server (1413019124032): Component "server:editor-node" waiting for delayed initialization
xdk:server (1413019124032): Component "server:cordova" starting import
xdk:server (1413019124046): Component "server:cordova" calling init()
xdk:server (1413019124379): Component "server:cordova" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019124379): Component "server:api-explorer" starting import
xdk:server (1413019124387): Component "server:api-explorer" calling init()
xdk:server (1413019124418): Component "server:api-explorer" finished initialization
xdk:server (1413019124418): Component "server:editor-node" finished delayed initialization
xdk:server (1413019124419): Component "server:projectInfo" calling start()
xdk:server (1413019124419): Component "server:projectInfo" finished start()
xdk:server (1413019124419): Component "server:ui-builder" calling start()
xdk:server (1413019124422): Component "server:ui-builder" finished start()
xdk:server (1413019124422): Component "server:emulator-webserver" calling start()
xdk:server (1413019124422): Component "server:emulator-webserver" finished start()
xdk:server (1413019124422): Component "server:editor-node" calling start()
xdk:server (1413019124425): Component "server:editor-node" finished start()
xdk:server (1413019124426): Intel XDK is initialized now
xdk:server (1413019124427): Writing to the server data file
editor:server (1413019124431): Startup complete, serving on port: 49790
xdk:server (1413019124432): Wrote server data to "C:\Users\Marco   Biagio17\AppData\Local\XDK\server-data.txt"
xdk:client (1413019124593): Successfully read server data file
xdk:client (1413019145796): Client cannot validate with server (status=0)
[Log closed from     xdk:client]
```

Comment: I think 172.0.0.1 is a typo on your question, should be 127.0.0.1 can you add some more information please? what version have you installed?

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall and reinstall the latest version of xdk, also it should maybe be 127.0.0.2, not 172.0.0.1